# Point email records to server without domain name?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email, mx

I have a Shopify site and have my www CNAME pointing to it.

However, I need to point my mail records to my VPS where I have set up webmail.

I am really confused with how to do this and have tried several ways.

From follow loads of different tutorials, my DNS is currently set up as such:

- mysite.com  |  A  |  204.93.213.45 (shopifys ip)
- mail.mysite.com |  A  | 111.00.111.00 (my servers ip)
- mail  |  A  | 111.00.111.00 (my servers ip)
- www  |  CNAME  |  mysite.myshopify.com
- mysite.com  | MX | 10 (?)

I can send emails from the vps under my domain, but not recieve them.

Can anyone at all tell me what I need to put in here to get this working?

Comment: What do you mean "without domain name"? It is the `MX` records in the DNS zone for your domain that control where the emails get processed.

Comment: @w3d what I mean is that normally I just point the Name Servers to my VPS and dont have to worry about the individual records above. In this instance I cant do that and have to point the WWW to one server and host emails on another

Comment: Have you tried setting your MX record to `mail.mysite.com` (an `A` record that points to your server)? Also reduce the TTL to 300 as it may take a bit of time for the change to propagate(?).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps to get this to work.

**Setup Email Hosting on Your Server**

Make sure your server is setup to receive email at your domain name.

**DNS Settings**

This is where most people make the error.  You need a `MX` record and an `A` record.

For example

```
example.com MX 10 mail.example.com

mail.example.com A 192.168.1.0
```

The `MX` records says that mail destined for `user@example.com` should be sent to the `mail.example.com` server.

`MX` records always have 3 parts:

```
example.com - the domain where the email is going to (user@domain.com)

10 - the priority level (useful when you have multiple SMTP servers)

mail server - the FQDN of the mail server
```

The `A` records says that `mail.example.com` is at `192.168.1.0`

**Common Errors**

Using the mail server name as the `MX` record:

```
mail.example.com MX 10 mail.example.com
```

This would be correct only for `user@mail.example.com` not for `user@example.com`.

Not supplying an A record for the email server `mail.example.com`.